# how to autoreplay FLV

Tags: html

Hi i am using FLV media player and i need to configure it auto replay. how to configure it?
i am doing it in the Dreamweaver. the code is

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" width="1080" height="880">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
  <param name="salign" value="lt" />

  <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_1&amp;streamName=file:///D%7C/flash/Skytel-D20---Gift&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=true" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
  <div>
    <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
  </div>
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.registerObject("FLVPlayer");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried this?

```
<param name="loop" value="true">
```

Comment: hello i have tried this but it was same. do you have any ideas?